# where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named b having a column j which is varchar(3) where I have stored values like

```
j    
----
a  
b
c
aa
ab
ac
```

when I write the statement like this

```
select * from b where j>"aa";
```

it shows

```
j
----
b
c
ab
ac
```

why is it so ...I thought it would show values upper than 'aa' which should ommit the values 'aa','a','b' and 'c' but it only ommits the value 'a' and 'aa' ...why is it so ?
I want to know how it is checks the values when I use multi characters

Comment: Because these are characters it's using alphabetical ordering... think of authors.  `Lee` comes after `Aberdeen` even though the latter has far more characters.  The evaluation is done on a char by char basis... so in your case anything greater than `a` as first, anything greater than `a` second *or not existing*.  Hence `'b'>'aa'` and `'ab'>'aa'`

Comment: You say it omits 'ab' but it is in your output?!

Only 'a' and 'aa' are omitted which seems correct to me, because you are looking for s.th. greater (not greater equal) than 'aa'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by lexicographical order. Like what you would find in a dictionary.

In a dictionary, first you compare the first letter and then get to the next letter.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple alphabetical order.

```
SELECT j FROM b ORDER BY j
```

would return:

```
j
----
a
aa
ab
ac
b
c
```

That should then make it clearer that the values > 'aa' are:

```
SELECT j FROM b WHERE j > 'aa' ORDER BY j
```

```
j
----
ab
ac
b
c
```

Comment: how does it match ab with a or b or c ???? is there any order in which it matches ???

Comment: @Nav: As I pointed out, it compares based on the alphabetical ordering of the values.

Answer (score 0):

When evaluating the string, `b`, `c`, `ab` and `ac` are being sorted *after* `aa`, and that is why they are being returned. Ultimately, it is due to how the string ordering is done for the table's locale.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the string comparison is done prioritizing the first letter.

If you want to skip all values with string length less than 2, then you need to have

```
SELECT * FROM b WHERE LENGTH(j) >= 2 AND j > 'aa'
```

Answer (score 0):

The where clause is comparing using dictionary order:

a
aa
ab
ac
b
c

Answer (score 0):

It does so because:

aa comes before b, c, ab, ac but doesn't come before a or aa in alphabetic ordering like `English language dictionary`.